# Sharepoint List using Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest

I followed this tutorial [Create a Sharepoint List using Rest Api](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-online/) but I had a

message error : `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"`

when I have clicked on the bottom "Create your custom list"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check(highlighted below)  the Allow the add-in to make app-only calls to SharePoint before you deploy the add-in to SharePoint

[image]

[Ref](http://asish.com.au/sharepoint-add-rest-api-failed-load-resource-server-responded-status-403-forbidden/)

Comment: thanks you M.Qassas for your consideration, but that doesn't work. (Already something I don't understand in the tutorial. He says to use Napa, so I don't find those permissions with Napa.)
After I have created the add-ins with visual studio in applying your councils but that don't work (always the same error : 403 (forbidden) ), the checkbox must be uncheck like your pictures, and under I must choose "Web" and "Full-Control" ?

Comment: How do you get to these settings?  What is the navigation route?

Comment: Ah - okay, it is in Visual Studio's app manifest.

Comment: @M.Qassas - I've seen Mathi's code - he's applied that setting, but he's still getting `Forbidden` when the addin tries to access the list.

Answer (score 1):

Forbidden error generally occurs because of these two reason-

1. Your Form Digest value is not correct.
2. The user you are running tests as doesn't have the requisite permissions.

To solve 1 - `use $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()` to get the form digest value.

This code may be helpful for you:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 100,
            'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Employees'
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
    function onSuccess(data) {
        alert(data + ' List Created');
    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
```

To solve case 2 - you have to give the requisite permission. For more [Click Here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript)